# Which one can I use instead of the word ''proven''

Tags: vocabulary

In 1980 virus was ''proven'' to be the reason of disease.
We can replace the word ''proven'' in this sentence with the word ''considered'' or ''shown''.

Comment: I would suggest, to identify; (was identified to be)

Comment: @Cardinal *identify* doesn't take infinitival complements -- we say "identified **as** the cause of the disease"

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks stoney for the correction. You know I checked google books and thought it's correct. I learner something new. Thanks.

Comment: @Cardinal You find this occasionally in bureaucratic and scientific use, but it is rare and jarring: see [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=identified+to+be%2Cidentified+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidentified%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidentified%20as%3B%2Cc0). Bureaucratic and scientific texts are not notable for clarity or idiomaticity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the word "**confirm**" is what you are looking for.

In 1980 virus was **confirmed** to be the reason of disease.

Neither "considered" nor "shown" has the same meaning with "proven", which means that something has been **put into a test** or has been **verified**.

Answer (score 0):

"Proven" means that we are now certain that this is true. "Considered" means that we thought about it as one of many possibilities, or think that it is the most likely possibility. "Shown" means essentially the same thing as proven in this context but has weaker connotations. If you said that something is "shown" I'd understand that to mean a high probability, but not the certainty that "proven" implies.

Answer (score 0):

Used in the context of your sentence, *demonstrated* is an exact synonym, meaning logically proven. In addition to the words Jay has given, other synonyms are *confirmed* and *found*. These also have a bit weaker connotation than *demonstrated* or *proven*, both of which mean a conclusion arrived at through a rigorous logical process.

However, *demonstrated* has similar but different meanings in other contexts. See [this dictionary entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/demonstrate?s=t).